# How to Format to_json output to go well with update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on Angular JS + Rails project . I am passing below JSON to angularJS which was created by rails to_json

**user_controller.rb**

```
render :json => current_user.to_json(:include => [:projects,:courses,:awards])
```

**User Controller output**

```
{"_json"=>   
   [{"id"=>21,
    "name"=>"Demo Name",
    "email"=>"demo@demo.com",
    "mobile"=>"",
    "dob"=>nil,
    "gender"=>nil,
    "address"=>nil,
    "intro"=>nil,
    "created_at"=>"2014-09-01T05:29:38.000Z",
    "updated_at"=>"2014-09-01T05:29:38.000Z",
    "projects"=>[{"id":1,"name":"Existing Project"}],
    "courses"=>[],
    "awards"=>[]
   }] 
}

Assigning data to angular $scope.userData = response._json
```

In Angular View , using HTML5 contenteditable (angular Directive), I am changing the value of the above object.

**Angular View**

```
<h3 ng-model="userData[0].name" contenteditable="true"></h3>
```

the content is changing as expected.

```
{"_json"=>   
      [{"id"=>21,
        "name"=>"UPDATED NAME HERE",
        "email"=>"demo@demo.com",
        "mobile"=>"",
        "dob"=>nil,
        "gender"=>nil,
        "address"=>nil,
        "intro"=>nil,
        "created_at"=>"2014-09-01T05:29:38.000Z",
        "updated_at"=>"2014-09-01T05:29:38.000Z",
        "projects"=>[{"id":1, "name":"Existing Project"},{"name":"ADDED NEW PROJECT HERE"}],
        "courses"=>[{"name":"ADDED NEW COURSE HERE"}],
        "awards"=>[]
       }] 
    }
```

Now I need to post this object to server and update user data and all the association data like projects which has both existing and new records , what is the right way and JSON format I need to post to make this process as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

User angular http post.

```
$http(
   method: 'POST'
   data: your_json_array_here
   url: your_url_to_controller_action

).success((data,status) -> 


).error((data,status) -> 


)
```

Answer (score 0):

Started using [Angular Rails Resoures](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource) , also another useful references is [RestAngular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)